# ssh connection between two distant computer

Tags: networking, transfer, scp

i try to transfer files between two distant ubuntu pc with scp. It works on a local network (using the wlan0 inet addr ip) but failed (connection refused on port 22) when the scp command comes from a computer outside the network. For example, i want to transfer a file from a machine in canada to a machine in usa. Yet, my port 22 has been open with `sudo ufw allow 22`.

Comment: When using `scp` you can either use the IP (which might be a problem for accessing a machine outside your network due to dynamic IP and what not) or the fully qualified domain name. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188289/79008).

Answer (score 1):

Port 22 is open in your local PC. Make sure that your Firewall/router has been configured to port-forward port 22 to the computer on your network correctly.

Comment: you are right. This is actuallly my problem. Thank you

Comment: @EricF If this post helped you solve the question, you should accept the answer.